# How to set the first message as unread for the receiver?

Tags: c#, twilio, twilio-api

I have a conversation with two participants:

```cs
var createdConversation = await ConversationResource.CreateAsync(uniqueName: uniqueName);

var sender = await ParticipantResource.CreateAsync(pathConversationSid: createdConversation.Sid, identity: "sender");
var receiver = await ParticipantResource.CreateAsync(pathConversationSid: createdConversation.Sid, identity: "receiver");
```

And I want to send a initial message in this newly created conversation:

```cs
var message = await MessageResource.CreateAsync(
    pathConversationSid: createdConversation.Sid,
    author: sender.Identity,
    body: intitialMessage);
```

After that, I want this new message to be `read` for the `sender` and `unread` for `receiver` which seems not possible.
I can set the `lastReadMessageIndex` of the `sender` to the created `message.Index` but this won't create read horizon for the `receiver`. And as long as the `lastReadMessageIndex` of the `receiver` is `null`, the `unreadMessagesCount` will be also `null`, and it will look like the `receiver` has no new messages in this conversation.

Any suggestions on how I can create a new conversation with initial message, which will be displayed as unread for one of the users?

Comment: I'm not sure about this, I'll check with the conversations team at Twilio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As there is no "easy way" to achieve this, I am loading the conversation and its messages to calculate the `unreadMessagesCount`.

```cs
var conversation = await UserConversationResource.FetchAsync(
    pathUserSid: userSid, 
    pathConversationSid: conversationSid);

var conversationHasNoReadHorizon = conversation.UnreadMessagesCount == null;
if (conversationHasNoReadHorizon)
{
    var messages = await MessageResource.ReadAsync(pathConversationSid: conversationSid);

    return messages.Count(message => message.Author != callerId);
}
else
{
    return conversation.UnreadMessagesCount ?? 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently it is not possible to do this. This has been raised internally at Twilio as a feature gap.

In the meantime you may need to workaround it. One thing I thought of would be to mark any conversations that have a `lastReadMessageIndex` of `null` as unread in your UI.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I need this information on the backend and I need to know the exact number of new messages. So, I have implemented something similar to what you have suggested on the server.

Comment: Is there a public page on which one can see the roadmap of twilio?

Comment: There is not, I'm afraid.